# an analysis problem continuous function

Tags: analysis

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(R,R)$ infinitely differentiable on real line, $f(x)=1$ for $ x\in[-1,1]$, and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin(-2,2)$. Prove that for any $C>0$, there exist an integer $n\ge0$, and a point $\xi\in R$ such that $|f^{(n)}(\xi)|>C$.

I trying to prove it by contradiction, but I cannot find any contradiction. I try to assume that: suppose there exist a $C>0$, for all integer $n\ge0$, and a point $\xi\in R$, we have $|f^{(n)}(\xi)|\le C$. I try to use Taylor expansion to get contradiction, but I failed. It seems to converge and no contradiction.

Does anyone have some ideas about this? Thank you!

Comment: First, get your quantifiers sorted out correctly for the contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all $|f^{(n)}(\xi)| \le C$, then use Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder to show that the Taylor series for $f$ about $a$ converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$.
That implies that $f$ is an entire function.  But a non-constant entire function can't be constant on an interval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any real analysis method? Since I am not so familiar with complex variables.

Comment: The series about a point outside $(-2,2)$ has all coefficients $0$.  If it converges, it converges to $0$...

Comment: Thank you! Yes. But what is the contradiction? I think the point must be in somewhere between 1 and 2, or -2 and -1, since other places are horizontal line.

Comment: The contradiction is that the series converges to $0$ but the function is not always $0$.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you so much!